# How to pass data between two iframes located in the same PHP page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, iframe

I have three iframes in my Queue Management page:

1. Iframe A - Contains table which list numbers that are in queue
2. Iframe B - Contains form which will process the number that is currently in its turn.
3. Iframe C - Contains table which lists all records of numbers history for that day.

Whenever I click on a number in Iframe A, I would like to pass the number to Iframe B so I can populate the form with the customer's data that's associated with the number I've passed. Then after the admin is done with processing the customer in Iframe B, the result will be refreshed in Iframe C.

So my issue now is, I can't figure out on how to post data from Iframe A to Iframe B and refresh the data with the populated form. The reason I'm using iframes is so I can refresh the iframes separately.

I'm using jQuery and Laravel and this is what I have so far in sending the data -

```
    $( "#btnExpress" ).click(function() {
        var ticket_number = $( "#tblExpress td" ).first().text();
        if (ticketNumber != 'Queue is empty.') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ URL::to('admin/qms_process') }}",
                type:"GET",
                data:{ticket_number:ticket_number},
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                },
                error:function(e){
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("No customer to process.")
        }

    });
```

Comment: Are the 3 elements on the same page? If so, do you really need to be using iframes?

Comment: Yes, it's all in the same page. If not, then what should I use?

Comment: Instead of IFRAMEs, which are mostly a legacy from pre-HTML5 times, you can use JavaScript (and JS libs) to dynamically manipulate the HTML markup, thus avoiding frames and their limitations and issues altogether.